# Remote desktop username password authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, rdp

How can I check that a username and password can be logged in remotely on remote machine using remote desktop API and C# code?

Comment: You can _check_ that using Active Directory, by checking whether the account you're checking has Remote Desktop privileges. Can you explain yourself a little better and show what you have found?

Comment: I'm looking for a method that can pass machine IP, username and password to it and it turned true or false for user privilege.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is what you're looking for:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET

Comment: Based on that article, I don't know how to check connection status programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
Process rdcProcess = new Process();
rdcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\cmdkey.exe");
rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/generic:TERMSRV/192.168.0.217 /user:" + "username" +  " /pass:" + "password";
rdcProcess.Start();

rdcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\mstsc.exe");
rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/v " + "192.168.0.217"; // ip or name of computer to connect
rdcProcess.Start();
```

The above code initiates a connection with .217 and I am not being prompted to provide a password.

If you don't want to keep stored credentials in repository, after this code you can call cmdkey.exe again with arguments

```
/delete:TERMSRV/192.168.0.217
```